# Unity - Limit Camera Movement XY axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following code which works really well for scrolling map using the draggable mouse. I am trying to define limits so that I cannot scroll too far in either the x or y co-ordinates. I've seen various examples of code, such as: 
    "transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp(-100, 100);" though have not been able to incorporate it into the code. I am a bit of a beginner to all this and have just done a 2D tutorial animating zombies and have a camera that can scroll, but would like to add limits to how far it can scroll in any given directions.

Thanks heaps

Adam

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ViewDrag : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 hit_position = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 current_position = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 camera_position = Vector3.zero;
    float z = 0.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            hit_position = Input.mousePosition;
            camera_position = transform.position;

        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            current_position = Input.mousePosition;
            LeftMouseDrag();        
        }
    }

    void LeftMouseDrag(){
        // From the Unity3D docs: "The z position is in world units from the camera."  In my case I'm using the y-axis as height
        // with my camera facing back down the y-axis.  You can ignore this when the camera is orthograhic.
        current_position.z = hit_position.z = camera_position.y;

        // Get direction of movement.  (Note: Don't normalize, the magnitude of change is going to be Vector3.Distance(current_position-hit_position)
        // anyways.  
        Vector3 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(current_position) - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hit_position);

        // Invert direction to that terrain appears to move with the mouse.
        direction = direction * -1;

        Vector3 position = camera_position + direction;

        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error you are getting? I imagine it is something along the lines of being unable to modify the return value of `position` because it is not a variable.

If this is the case, you should however be able to set the whole position vector at once. So try something along the lines of this:

```cs
var pos = transform.position;
transform.position = new Vector3(
    Math.clampf(pos.x, -100, 100), 
    Math.clampf(pos.y, -100, 100),
    pos.z
);
```

You may need to swap around clamping Y and Z, depending on how you are using them.